# How to check cpu usage for scripts and gameObjects in unity?

Tags: memory-management, unity-game-engine

I have created the action game in unity. But the frame rate is too low on mobile devices. How do I check how much cpu is currently using for my scripts and gameObject in unity?. Similar like  how we do in "Instruments" in iOS.

Comment: At the Unity site you can find a [check list](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/MobileOptimisation.html) of dos and donts and a small description of [Profiling](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/MobileProfiling.html). I wrote an article about the different strategies in my [blog](http://www.scio.de/en/blog-a-news/scio-development-blog-en/entry/analysing-performance-in-unity3d-ios-apps).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is built-in function called `Profiler` in unity3D though It's restricted if you are using free ver of Unity
Check http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/iphone-InternalProfiler.html

In the case you have Xcode on your system,You can also use Instruments for your unity project.

1.Check `Development build` in the build menu and build your unity project into iOS/OSX app.

2.Open Xcode and select `Edit Scheme....` then choose `Debug` for `Build Configuration`

3.Do Clean and Build

4.Select the Profile and Run `Instruments`

If you want to check the usage of specific script you wrote,Check

```
BehaviourManager::Update -> MonoBehaviour::Update -> CallUpdateMethod
```